# How to dynamically instantiate a class with parameterized constructor using std::vector?

Tags: c++

I want to dynamically instantiate the object using vector, However, I don't know how to pass the parameter to the constructor.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Player {
    
    public:
    Player(int id, string name)
     : p_id(id)
     , p_name(name)
                                                                                     
  {
  }
  
   public:
      int p_id;
      string p_name;
   };

int main() {

vector<Player>  player;      **//How to instantiate the object with parametrized constructor** 
    
player.resize(sizeof(player));
  
return 0;
   
}
```

Comment: Do you want a vector of N identical copies of `Player`?

Comment: `std::vector<Player> player(1, Player{0, ""});`

Comment: `sizeof(player)` is not a meaningful number of players; it's the size _in bytes_ of a single player.

Comment: `std::vector<Player> players = {{0, "Alice"}, {42, "Bob"}};`?

Comment: @MSalters for max confusion `player` is the name of a vector of `Player`. `sizeof(player)` is the size of a `std::vector<Player>`, when probably OP wanted `player.size()` (and give the vector a better name)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume, you may want to look toward this:

```
class Player {
public:
    Player() = default;
    Player(int id, string name): p_id(id), p_name(name) {}
private:
    int p_id;
    string p_name;
};

int main() {
    vector<Player> players;
    // construct a Player from an int and a string 
    players.emplace_back(33, "Foo");
}
```

Here, we use a `std::vector` member function [`emplace_back()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back), which constructs an object inside (at the back) the vector.

---

There are other thing(s) to note in your code:

```
players.resize(sizeof(players)); // Is nonsensical
```

You should check the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize) on `std::vector::resize` and the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof) on `sizeof()`. In short, we can use `resize(n)` to change the amount of elements in the container.

We can either **increase the number of elements**, by providing such `n` that is greater than the current `size()`. In which case, additional default-inserted elements are appended.

Or **decrease the number of elements** in the container by providing smaller `n`. In which case, the content of the container is reduced to its first `n` elements, removing those beyond (and destroying them).

Note, that this function alters the actual contents of a container:

```
players.emplace_back(11, "Foo");
players.emplace_back(22, "Bar");
players.emplace_back(33, "Buz");

players.resize(2); // Now, players.size() == 2
// ...and there are no Buz among the players
```

That's why passing the `sizeof(players)` to `resize()` is meaningless, especially when we consider that the `sizeof()` returns a **number of bytes**.

If you want to have a `vector` with some number of pre-constructed `Player` objects in it, you should use vector's **fill constructor**:

```
// Ten objects of class Player
vector<Player> players(10, Player(0, ""));
// Ten default constructed objects of type Player
vector<Player> players(10);  // Player has to have a default constructor
```

Comment: you should also mention how one can call `resize`

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number yeah, it will be appropriate

Comment: Thank you. My question has been answered correctly.